# What is the easiest way to convert ActiveX to something compatible in all browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, web, activex

I'm working with some js files that have ActiveX requests. My job is to make the files work in all browsers. Is there an easy painless way to make the files work in all browsers, because I'm starting to get at my wit's end.

Comment: Hooo boy, I feel for you, there. It really depends on what the components do. Any (simple) animation can (generally) be done using Javascript and CSS inside the browser. Any data-related components will depend on if you have access to the server, and your comfort level with server technologies. I am not too sad to say that you will _not_ be able to get ActiveX running in all browsers. Sorry.

Comment: Please post much more specific information on these ActiveX controls.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use the ActiveX controls for? Obviously, ActiveX controls are never going to work in *all* browsers since they contain native x86 code, though there are some (Windows-only) extensions for both [Firefox](http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgllffgicojgllpmdbemgglaponefajn) that seem to add some kind of support for ActiveX controls.

Otherwise, if you can move away from ActiveX, your best bet might be Java, but then again it really depends on what you need to achieve; most browsers have heavy restrictions when it comes to accessing local files, which is what ActiveX controls are typically used for.